# is it possible to pass data from an uploader (file input tag) to another one?

Tags: jquery, uploader

Is it possible to pass all data from an uploader (file input tag) to another one?
in javascript or jquery.

What I want to do is to load a file in one uploader and pass it to another one

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is not possible, but I have to wonder why you need this.  Once you get the file in a JS variable, you can do whatever you like with it.  Do you have a jQuery plugin attaching to a particular file input?

Answer (score 0):

Due to security issues you have no access to the values of those tags.

Using File API however you can read the selected file into memory and the do any number of things with it.

You can resize an image to the size of a thumbnail and put it in the source of a new  by base64 encoding it.

Comment: First check for target browser compatibility (lookup File API on caniuse.com).

Comment: [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) should be a good starting point for reading files into memory.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible.

However, if you must. There are a few external components like flash's upload component of java applets that will give you the path.

Comment: In Java as well as Flash (AFAIK) using the "filepath" you read from the user inputed file in another user input does not grant you access to the file.

Comment: The OS & Browser/Flash/Java mitigate you access rights to the files. And they all keep track of which user input was granted access to the file. Otherwise constructing a slew of user inputs with "/etc/passwd" or "/etc/shadow" or whatever, would be trivial.